# Ubuntu on Asus x550ca Laptop

Tags: drivers, asus

i would like to know if there is the possibility of install ubuntu in my laptop asus x550c. How should i proceed to install all the drivers correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux , this may help u...

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on Asus X450L.

Everything is working fine **except** the *brightness keyboard shortcut* and *touchpad* not working.

But what counts is the touchpad and the workaround is only to use mouse for now. This is a kernal problem and is consistent with other Asus laptops.

A bug has been issued in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/).

So,if you do install any version of ubuntu [or 14.04] and the touchpad works. Do let me know!

Answer (score -1):

As answer before, you install any linux and it doesn't need any drivers.
A think ubuntu needs too resources which your asus doesn't have, you can install it but it may to be slow due to the desktop is unyty, it needs minium 1 GB in RAM
you didn't give us ypurs specifications
You should to install some linux whith a soft desktop, like Lubuntu, Xubuntu, linux mint that's very well and fast
If you know enought about linux, you can install the debian's kernel and after install any desktop screen like lxd, xfce, gnome or gnome-core, mate